# How do I retrieve a java thread using its name?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, thread-safety, runnable

I'm having a problem with threads in java, how do I search for a thread I created from her name?

I created the following Thread below:

```
 new Thread("operator_conection") {

            private Server server;

            @Override
            public void run() {               
                try {
                    this.server = new Server(3242);
                    this.server.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
            }
          }.start();
```

How do I recover this Thread? Note that it has the name "operator_conection"

Is there something more direct? I'm using java 8

Comment: Sorry, it is not acceptable to post a new question when there is an existing one on the same topic, just on the off-chance that a newer solution exists. Yes, Stack Overflow suffers from the problem of outdated answers; there is [an initiative to try to address that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project). The solution is not to post the same question again. The useful information will just end up fragmented across multiple questions, and it make finding solutions harder, not easier.

Comment: Often, if there is a newer solution to a task that was previously tricky or ugly or long-winded, users will retrospectively add it as an answer to a question, if the question is high-profile enough. That one is quite active. Such answers are likely to be down the bottom, so remember to check there too.

Comment: @Michael Hello Michael all right? I edited the question, the original answer is 9 years ago, during this time we had updates in java, the answer is very old, so I want to see if there is another solution, because the way it was presented will be unfeasible the application here :)

Comment: @Michael I edited the question, is this more acceptable? And it is different from the original 9 years ago, because in question it answers how to search a thread for an ID, this question of mine is to search for a Thread by name

Comment: If you want to get a thread by name, there is also a question about that. I've added it to the list of duplicates. Unfortunately, with or without the edit, this is a duplicate of questions we've had before. The fact that you're asking at a later point in time is not relevant, the underlying question is the same. If there are newer answers, they can be added to the existing questions. While it may benefit *you* to have people answer this question, it benefits *everyone* if all the answers are in one place.

Comment: Sorry if this system seems suboptimal but that's the system we have. I agree it's not perfect and can understand why it might be frustrating. The site is not really designed around the idea that technology can change and answers can become outdated, but it's the site you're choosing to participate in

Comment: The whole idea of getting a thread by name is wrong.  You _can_ get a list of threads from the system with the `Thread.enumerate(...)` method but the right question is why would you?  You could store the `Thread` instance that you created in a field so you can refer to it again.  And the next question is what are you planning to do with the thread?  If you are trying to get data out of it then there are much better ways to do so.  About the only thing you should be doing is calling `interrupt()` or `join()` on it.  If you take a step back and ask your _real_ question then maybe we can help.

Comment: Right, newer use tread's name/id to lookup a particular thread. Just store the reference to your thread and access it by this reference. Thread names are sutable for debug info, logging etc.

Comment: @Gray Hi how are you? This reference-keeping solution might be a good idea... but let me explain my problem better, I will make a call via webservice to start a connection, this connection should be unique, there will be several devices that will use is only connection to perform a series of actions, so I figured this connection would look better in a thread, I imagined a container too, but I did not want to leave for the container because I do not know how to use :(

Comment: @Gray If I'm going to use a thread list how do I retrieve the specific Thread, asking better, should this thread list be something like a singleton? Should it be a static list or something?

Comment: Sorry dude but you should create a new question with more details.  I just don't have enough information to comment.